# Mule outbound endpoint level statistics to facilitate integration testing

Tags: mule

I am looking for a pragmatic solution to do Integration testing of our Integration tier based on Mule.

This article [here](http://soa.sys-con.com/node/665712?page=0,1) has some excellent pointers about it, but looks a tad outdated. I am reproducing an excellent idea from the article here

> Keeping track of the delivery of messages to external systems. Interrogating all the systems that have been contacted with test messages after the suite has run to ensure they all received what was expected would be too tedious to realize. How to keep track of these test messages? One option could be to run Mule ESB with its logging level set to DEBUG and analyze the message paths by tracking them with their correlation IDs. This is very possible. I decided to follow a simpler and coarser approach, which would give me enough certitude about what happened to the different messages I have sent. For this, I decided to leverage component routing statistics to ensure that the expected number of messages where routed to the expected endpoints (including error messages to error processing components). Of course, if two messages get cross-sent to wrong destinations, the count will not notice that. But this error would be caught anyway because each destination will complain about the error, hence raising the count of error messages processed.

Using this technique when I test my integration tier I will not have to stand up all the external systems and can test the integration tier in isolation which would be great.

@David Dassot has provided a reference implementation as well, however I think it was based on Mule 2.X and hence I cannot find the classes in the Mule 3.X codebase.

Looking around I did find [FlowConstructStatistics](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/management/stats/FlowConstructStatistics.html) but this is flow specific statistics and I am looking for endpoint specific statistics.

I do agree that as a work around we could wrap all outbound endpoints within sub-flows and get this working, but I would like to avoid doing this ...

Any techniques that help query the endpoint for the number of calls made, payload passed through the endpoints would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take a look to JMX, perhaps what you need is available right there.

Otherwise, if looging is not enough, and upgrading to the enterprise version is not ok for you. Give it a try to the [endpoint level notifications](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications).

Comment: I will check JMX . We are on enterprise anything specific you can point at?

Comment: Give a look to insights and business events

Comment: I have had a look at the Business Events sections, the "default event tracking" applies to only some message processors and putting in a custom events is not quite feasible. With JMX they do not expose endpoint level metrics.But the endpoint level notifications is exactly what I needed